# Hiding radio options depending on other seperate radio option in knockout

Tags: json, knockout.js

I plan to have two sets of radio options on my form, one radio called `Operating System` and another radio called `Database`.

The option selected by the `Operating System` radio dictates the values available for selection in the `Database` radio group.

In my json object the `requires` field indicates the visibility of the option when the sku of the Operating System is selected. If no `requires` field is provided for a database option, then it will always be available regardless of the selected operating system.

How would one approach this in knockout, or do I need to rethink my approach?

[My jsfiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/FB829/1/)

```
var osOptions = [{
  name: "Windows Standard",
    sku: "201",
},{
    name: "Windows Enterprise",
    sku: "202",
}, {
    name: "CentOS Linux",
    sku: "203",
}, {
    name: "Debian",
    sku: "204",
}];

var databaseOptions = [{
    name: None,
}, {
    name: "SQL Express",
    sku: 401,
    requires: ["201", "202"]
}, {
    name: "SQL Standard",
    sku: 402,
    requires: ["202"]
}, {
    name: "MySQL",
    sku: "MySQL1",
    requires: ["201", "202", "203"]
}, {
    name: "RavenDb",
    sku: 403,
}, {
    name: "MongoDB",
    sku: 404,
    requires: ["204"]
}];

function viewModel() {
    this.os = osOptions;
    this.database = databaseOptions;
    this.selectedOs = ko.observable();
    this.selectedDb = ko.observable();
}
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel);

<!- view html -->
<h1>Select OS:</h1>
<div data-bind="foreach: os" >
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="optionsGroup" data-bind="attr: {value: name}, checked: $root.selectedOs" />
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </div>    
</div>
<h1>Select Db</h1>
<div data-bind="foreach: database" >
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="optionsGroup" data-bind="attr: {value: name}, checked: $root.selectedDb" />
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: can you plz post example of what you have tried or any code you have at least as a start?

Comment: Also, your `data` variable is wrong in many ways.  You can't use semicolons, or equal signs in objects.  Also `[ { "201" } ]` doesn't make sense.  I think you meant `[ "201" ]`.  I found these while trying to write a solution to your question, and gave up.  Please try to make questions easier to answer in the future.  Please read [this checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Very sorry for the errors, I appreciate everyone takes time to look and help. I have included a jsfiddle for my progress so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a different computed collection `availableDatabases` where

- first I would look up the currently selected OS
- then I would use the `ko.utils.arrayFilter` to filter out the databases where the the `requires` array does not contain the selected `sku`.

So I would write something like this:

```
this.availableDatabases = ko.computed(function() {
    var selectedOsName = this.selectedOs();

    var selectedOs = ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.os, function(os){
       return os.name ==  selectedOsName;
    }, this);

    if (!selectedOs)
        return [];

    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.database, function(db){
        return db.requires && db.requires.indexOf(selectedOs.sku) > -1;
    }, this)

}, this);
```

And use this new collection in the view:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: availableDatabases" >
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="optionsGroup" 
             data-bind="attr: {value: name}, checked: $root.selectedDb" />
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6eYJH/)

Note If you have the `sku` instead of the `name` as the `value` for you first radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="optionsGroup" 
                    data-bind="attr: {value: sku}, checked: $root.selectedOs" />
```

Then there is no lookup needed in the computed because `selectedOs` would contain the `sku` property directly ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YYKmT/))...

Comment: Yes!! Only question I have is, when selecting the database, the original OS radio is deselected. Any way to keep the OS radio selection shown also? screenshot from chrome here http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/1086/igy5.png. Other than that, its great :)

Comment: @g18c just give your radio button groups different names: like name='os' and name='db' http://jsfiddle.net/6eYJH/1/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FB829/9/)

You can create an computed that retrieves the available databases.

JS :

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.os = osOptions;
    this.database = databaseOptions;
    this.selectedOs = ko.observable();
    this.selectedDb = ko.observable();

    this.availableDatabase = ko.computed(function () {
        var osSku = self.selectedOs();
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.database, function (dbItem) {
            if (osSku == null) return false;

            if (dbItem.requires == null) return true;

            var dbs =  ko.utils.arrayFirst(dbItem.requires, function (requiredOS) {
                return requiredOS == osSku;
            }) != null;
            return dbs;

        });

    });
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Not sure, certainly wasn't me I gave you +1 thank you for the help I appreciate you taking the time