# knockout foreach binding not working when viewmodel used as a sub-view-model wizard style dialog

Tags: knockout.js

I am creating a wizard that consists of multiple sub-view-models.

One [view-model (step 3) is a copy of this knockout form and consists of two radio button groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644324/hiding-radio-options-depending-on-other-seperate-radio-option-in-knockout), where the first group controls what options are available in the second group.

I am having trouble binding the radio buttons when used in this sub-view, whilst it works as a standalone view-model, it seems when used as a sub-view the `self.availableDatabases` ko.computed function is never called (or in other words, it seems the view is not bound to the viewmodel).

The select db radio group is bound to the child's view model availableDatabases with the  below code:

```
<h1>Select OS:</h1>
<div data-bind="foreach: os" >
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="os" data-bind="attr: {value: name}, checked: $root.selectedOs" />
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </div>    
</div>
<h1>Select DB:</h1>
<div data-bind="foreach: availableDatabases" >
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="db" data-bind="attr: {value: name}, checked: $root.selectedDb" />
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </div>    
</div>
```

[The fiddle for the entire wizard code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/g18c/bHCwd/3/), any ideas what I am doing wrong with my integration to the sub-view-model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `$parent` instead of `$root`.

The `$root` references your main view model what you pass in the applyBindings call in your case `ViewModel` but you have the `selectedOs` and `selectedDb` properties on your `ConfigureModel`.

So you need to use `$parent` to "go one level up" in the foreach to access your properties (or you could use `$root.configureModel().selectedOs` to go all the way to top and go one level down to your `configureModel`)

```
<h1>Select OS:</h1>
<div data-bind="foreach: os" >
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="os" data-bind="attr: {value: name}, 
               checked: $parent.selectedOs" />
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </div>    
</div>
<h1>Select DB:</h1>
<div data-bind="foreach: availableDatabases" >
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="db" data-bind="attr: {value: name}, 
               checked: $parent.selectedDb" />
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/qRHh3/)

You can read about these Binding Context properties in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html).

Comment: Ok really appreciate the help - this is working great now. One final query, how would one go about selecting the first element of the radio option so there is always the option selected (i.e. so Windows Standard, the first option, is always ticked when the view loads)?

Comment: You can just a default value to your selectedOs observable: `self.selectedOs = ko.observable(self.os[0].name);`

Comment: Sorry @nemsev cant figure out, how one would set the selectedDb to the first option when the Os changes, could you kindly point me in the right direction i get the filtered db list but dont know how to set the value and wether i should use thr sku or name.

Comment: You need to subscribe on the change of the `availableDatabases` computed. Inside the change handler you can set the `selectedDb` http://jsfiddle.net/SMUSv/ Note that I've moved the setting of `selectedOs` default value after the subscribition to make work for the initial selection.